# Variable as partition date in dbt, when loading BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, dbt

i am facing some issues when trying to load a partitioned table using the incremental mode. Each partition is created based on a execution_date variable i pass as an argument.
For some reasons, the new partition is always generated using CurrentDate as the partition value. Even tough the variable passed as argument as a different date value.
I have defined a macro to format the variable passed through the command line.
Please find below the code for the macro:

```
{% macro formatted_date(execution_date) %}
  {% set execution_date_obj = modules.datetime.datetime.strptime(execution_date|string, "%Y%m%d") %}
  {{ return(execution_date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And below is how I have defined the dbt model for loading the table:

```
{{config(alias='unipr_salesforce',
    materialized = 'incremental',
    partitions = [formatted_date(var('execution_date'))]
)}}
```

Finally, this is the command use to run the dbt model, where you can see the variable used as argument:

```
unipr-subscription-pipeline toledanof$ dbt run --target dev --profiles-dir ./ --vars 'execution_date : "20210310"'
```

Every time i run the dbt model, the partition generated correspond to the CurrentDate, regardless the execution_date value.
Does anybody know a possible reason for this behaviour? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

it seems there are a couple of issues with what you're trying to do:

1. You need to tell dbt the name of the column you want to partition by to be able to write to a specific partition. If you don't, dbt treats this as a model that is updated incrementally but has no partitioning
2. To be able to specify what partitions you want to replace, you'd need to use the `insert_overwrite` [strategy](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#the-insert_overwrite-strategy). When you don't specify a strategy explicitly, dbt defaults to the `merge` [strategy](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#the-merge-strategy) which scans the entire table to decide what to update and what to insert (and I believe requires that you specify a `unique_key` in your config)

One way to solve this would be to also include the current date as a column in your model and use that as your partition key. Here's what your config might look like:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    partition_by={'field': 'current_date', 'data_type': 'date'},
    incremental_strategy='insert_overwrite',
    partitions=[formatted_date(var('execution_date'))]
  )
}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The idea is not to partition by field, but by ingestion time. I have managed to create a target partitioned table using materialized = 'table'. Doing that way, dbt automatically partitioned the table based on the pseudo-column _PARTITIONDATE.

However, we would like to use materialized='incremental', and so far I have not been able to sort it out.